# apriori algorithm takes time in r

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I am dealing with a dataset having 614 variables and 1348 transactions and trying to run it in R, but, the process time is too high that the code is never showing the final output and my laptop is hanging.

```
a <- read.csv("v.csv")
library(arules)
for(i in 1:ncol(a))
    a[i]<-  as.factor(a[,i])
rules <- apriori(a,parameter=list(supp = .5 , conf = 0.9, target="rules"))
summary(g)
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Try a small subset first and then build on it. I suspect you won't be able to do a lot, since you appear to have 2 data points per parameter.

Comment: It was working on small datasets. But, also on the "Adult" inbuilt dataset having 2127 obs and 4 vbls..Can't understand why it is not working here..

Comment: The built-in Adult data set is highly preprocessed and makes sure that the translation into binary items in transactions works. Do the following: as(a, "transactions"). It should tell you how many items are created...

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue could be related to the data. I think some of your variables in `a` might be continuous variables and `as.factor` will create a factor value for each of the unique values. apriori will then try to convert each factor value into an individual item creating an extremely large matrix which causes your laptop to hang.

**Note:** This is pure speculation since I do not know how your data looks like.